# How to place 2 responsive 4by3 elements in one row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to place two charts in a row using Bootstrap. Each chart should use 1/2 of the total width and the height of the chart should adapt to maintain a 4 by 3 aspect ratio.

I have tried with the following HTML, but each chart will occupy the whole width and be placed above each other:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the layout I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find any `embed-responsive` usage in Bootstrap 3 documentation. I think it's been added starting from Bootstrap 4 Alpha (and still used in Beta). Run my code to see if this is what you're trying to do.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I upgraded my Bootstrap code to 4.0.0-beta and now it seems to work.